# xml parsing is done but the values are not added to the array in iphone 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <xml_api_reply version="1">
- <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
- <forecast_information>
  <city data="" /> 
  <postal_code data="" /> 
  <latitude_e6 data="50500000" /> 
  <longitude_e6 data="30500000" /> 
  <forecast_date data="2011-05-26" /> 
  <current_date_time data="2011-05-26 04:00:00 +0000" /> 
  <unit_system data="US" /> 
  </forecast_informatioin have the n>
- <current_conditions>
  <condition data="Clear" /> 
  <temp_f data="52" /> 
  <temp_c data="11" /> 
  <humidity data="Humidity: 62%" /> 
  <icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif" /> 
  <wind_condition data="Wind: NW at 9 mph" /> 
  </current_conditions>
  </weather>
  </xml_api_reply>
```

Hi this is element .h-------------------/

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface TWeatherElement : NSObject 
{
    NSString *mIcon;
    //NSString *mForecastdate;
    NSString *mCurrentdate;
    NSString *mConditionname;
    NSString *mMintemp;
    NSString *mMaxtemp;
    NSString *mWind;
    NSString *mHumidity;
    NSString *mWeather;
    NSString *mXmlapireply;

 }

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *icon;
//@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *forecastdate;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *currentdate;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *conditionname;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *mintemp;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *maxtemp;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *wind;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *humidity;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *weather;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *xmlapireply;


@end

this is element .m----------------------/
#import "TWeatherElement.h"


@implementation TWeatherElement
@synthesize icon = mIcon;
//@synthesize forecastdate = mForecastdate;
@synthesize currentdate = mCurrentdate;
@synthesize conditionname = mConditionname;
@synthesize mintemp = mMintemp;
@synthesize maxtemp = mMaxtemp;
@synthesize wind = mWind;
@synthesize humidity = mHumidity;
@synthesize weather = mWeather;
@synthesize xmlapireply =mXmlapireply;


-(void)dealloc
{
    [mIcon release];
    //[mForecastdate release];
    [mCurrentdate release];
    [mConditionname release];
    [mMintemp release];
    [mMaxtemp release];
    [mWind release];
    [mHumidity release];
    [mWeather release];
    [mXmlapireply release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end

this is parser.h---------------/

#import "TWeatherElement.h"//this is the class where the elements are Created
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface TWeatherParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate> 
{
    NSMutableArray *mParserArray;
    NSXMLParser *mXmlParser;
    NSMutableString *mCurrentElement;
    BOOL elementFound;
    TWeatherElement *mWeather;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentElement;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *mParserArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TWeatherElement *weatherobj;

-(void)getInitialiseWithData:(NSData *)inData;

@end


this is parser.m--------------------/

#import "TWeatherParser.h"
#import "JourneyAppDelegate.h"
#import "api.h"
#import "TWeatherController.h"
//#define kParsingFinishedNotification @"ParsingFinishedNotification"


@implementation TWeatherParser
@synthesize weatherobj = mWeather;
@synthesize currentElement = mCurrentElement;
@synthesize mParserArray;

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
    self.currentElement =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        mWeather =nil;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)getInitialiseWithData:(NSData *)inData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:inData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];   //YES if the receiver should report the namespace and qualified name of each element, NO otherwise. The default value is NO
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:YES]; //YES if the receiver should report the scope of namespace declarations, NO otherwise. The default value is NO.
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];//YES if the receiver should report declarations of external entities, NO otherwise. The default value is NO

    [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"%@",parser);

    [parser release];
}



-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString*) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict
{
    //
//  if (nil!= qualifiedName)
//  {
//      elementName = qualifiedName;
//  }
//  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"weather"])
//  {
//      self.weatherobj = [[TWeatherElement alloc]init];
//  }
//  else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_date_time"]||
//          [elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"]||
//          [elementName isEqualToString:@"humidity"]||
//          [elementName isEqualToString:@"icon"]||
//          [elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition"]||
//          [elementName isEqualToString:@"low"]||
//          [elementName isEqualToString:@"high"])
//  {
//      self.currentElement = [NSMutableString string];
//  }
//  else 
//  {
//      self.currentElement = nil;
//  }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"xml_api_reply"])
    {
        mWeather = [[TWeatherElement alloc]init];
        NSString *data8= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"version"];
        if(data8 !=nil)
            mWeather.xmlapireply =data8 ;
        [mParserArray addObject:data8];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"weather"])
    {
        NSString *data0= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"module_id"];
        if(data0 !=nil)
            mWeather.weather =data0 ;
        NSLog(@"weather==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"module_id"]);
    }
     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_date_time"])
     {
         NSString *data1= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
         if (data1 !=nil) 
             mWeather.currentdate =data1;
         NSLog(@"current_date_time==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
     }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"])
            {
                NSString *data2= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data2 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.conditionname=data2;
                NSLog(@"condition==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);

            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"humidity"])
        {
                NSString *data3= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data3 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.humidity =data3;
                NSLog(@"humidity==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);

            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"icon "])
            {
                NSString *data4= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data4 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.icon =data4;
                NSLog(@"icon==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);

}
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition "])
            {
                NSString *data5= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data5 !=nil) 
                    mWeather.wind =data5;
                NSLog(@"wind_condition==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"low "])
            {
                NSString *data6= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data6 !=nil)                    mWeather.mintemp = data6;
                NSLog(@"low==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
            }
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"high "])
            {
                NSString *data7= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
                if (data7 !=nil)                    mWeather.maxtemp =data7;                
                NSLog(@"high==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
            }
    //{
////        self.currentElement = [NSMutableString string];
////    }
////    else 
////    {
////        self.currentElement = nil;
////    }



}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString*)string
{
    if (nil!= self.currentElement)
    {
        [self.currentElement appendString:string];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qName
{
    if (nil != qName)
    {
        elementName  = qName;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_date_time "]) 
    {
        mWeather.currentdate = self.currentElement;

    }
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition "]) 
{
    mWeather.conditionname = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"humidity "]) 
{
    mWeather.humidity = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"icon "]) 
{
    mWeather.icon = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition "]) 
{
    mWeather.wind = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"low "]) 
{
    mWeather.mintemp = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"high "]) 
{
    mWeather.maxtemp = self.currentElement;

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"weather"]) 
{
    [mParserArray addObject:mWeather];
    NSLog(@"mDataArray count = %d",[mParserArray count]);
    [mWeather release];

}   
}

//-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
//{
//  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ]postNotificationName:kParsingFinishedNotification object:mParserArray];
//}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    self.weatherobj = nil;
    self.currentElement = nil;
}
@end


this is controllerclass.h---------------------/

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TWeatherParser.h"
@class TWeatherParser;


@interface TWeatherController : UITableViewController {

    UITableView *mTableView;
    NSMutableArray *mImage;
    NSMutableArray *weatherarray;
    TWeatherParser *weather;




}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *mTableView;


@end


this is controller class.m----------------------/
#import "TWeatherController.h"
#import "TWeatherCell.h"
#import "TWeatherElement.h"
#import "TWeatherParser.h"
#import "api.h"


@implementation TWeatherController
@synthesize mTableView;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
    }
    return self;
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

/*
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
*/


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    api *ap = [[api alloc]init];
    NSData *aData = [ap getBusXMLAtStop:@"1"];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //NSInteger value = [str intValue];
    if (str)
    {
        NSLog(@"this is success %@",ap.dataReply);
        TWeatherParser *parser = [[TWeatherParser alloc]init];
        [parser getInitialiseWithData:ap.dataReply];
        [parser release];


    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"cannot fetch" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertview show];
        [alertview release];
    }


    [ap release];



}

/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //TWeatherParser *parse = [[TWeatherParser alloc]init];
    //weatherarray = parse.mParserArray;
    return [weatherarray count];

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


   TWeatherCell *cell =(TWeatherCell *) [mTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TWeatherCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    TWeatherElement *newobj = [weather.mParserArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([newobj.icon isEqualToString:@"http://\n"])
    {
        cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
    }
    else {
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newobj.icon]];
        cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [imageData release];
    }
    cell.reportdate.text = newobj.currentdate;
    cell.conditionname.text = newobj.conditionname;
    cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",newobj.mintemp,newobj.maxtemp];
    cell.twodirection.text = newobj.wind;
    cell.humidity.text = newobj.humidity;
    //cell.reportdate.text = newobj.currentdate;


    //cell.reportdate.text =@"My journey";
//  cell.conditionname.text = @"raji";
//  cell.twotemp.text = @"pradeep"; 
//  cell.twodirection.text = @"harish";
//  cell.humidity.text =@"23";
//  cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    */
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    return 100.0;


}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Hi @Aman this is link for my xml file http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000

Comment: Hey Rani, have you tried removing all the lines `NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, `self.mParserArray = temp;` and `[temp release];`? That's basically what I said in the answer below. You only need the line `[mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];`

Comment: check the answer given below if problem persist let me know i will mail you the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the code

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.mParserArray=temp;
        [temp release];


        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

    }
```

You need to create the array once and assign mParserArray(which should have retain property ) to it. Later you should keep adding objects to your mParserArray like

```
mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
```

Do not create array and override them in every if statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's intended, but what currently happening is:

When you find a predefined element (any you've named in an if-statement), you create an empty array (temp) and add your object in it. The XML parser then proceeds to the next element. In the next element, you empty your array and add that object.

So, in the end, only the LAST element found is added: xml_api_reply

Solution? Try to create an array in something like `viewDidLoad` and do not create an empty array in every element, but add everything to an existing one (so: without creating an empty one and overwriting your existing array with it)

To make thing clear, using this code should do the trick:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString*) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"xml_api_reply"])
    {
        mWeather = [[TWeatherElement alloc]init];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_date_time"])
    {
        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"])
    {
        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"humidity"])
    {
        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"icon"])
    {
        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition"])
    {
        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"low"])
    {
        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"high"])
    {
        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the given below code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


fcdayofweek = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
fclow = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
fchigh = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
fccondition = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
fcicon = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000"];
NSLog(@"%@",url);


NSURL *xmlURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url];
[url release];
//[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
//[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
NSLog(@"Start parsing");
[xmlURL release];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
[parser release];
parser = nil;

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

In your parser delgate method use the code:

```
       /*------- prasing delegate methods ---------------*/
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"Data is temporarily unavailable . Please try again in a few minutes." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
[errorAlert release];

}




- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{   

 // NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude_e6"]) {

    NSLog(@"latitude ==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
    // clear out our story item caches...

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude_e6"])
{

    NSLog(@"longitude==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"forecast_date"])
{

    NSLog(@"forecastdate==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_date_time"])
{

    NSLog(@"current_date_time===%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"unit_system"])
{

    NSLog(@"unit_system==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
}
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"temp_f"])
{

    NSLog(@"temp_f==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"temp_c"])
{

    NSLog(@"temp_c==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"humidity"])
{

    NSLog(@"humidity==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
}

else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition"])
{

    NSLog(@"wind_condition==%@",[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]);
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"day_of_week"])
{
    [fcdayofweek addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"low"])
{

    [fclow addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"high"])
{

    [fchigh addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"icon"])
{

    [fcicon addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"])
{

    [fccondition addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];
}
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
//NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Price"]) {
    // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...

    //NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
}


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
//NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
// save the characters for the current item...


}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

NSLog(@"all done!");

//[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishedparsing) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];


}
```

Comment: Then send me your code or give your email so that i can send you the code , my email id is mentioned in my profile.Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the data in console?

Comment: how can i judge the problem without seeing it completely?

Comment: hi i solve the problem but i face another problem in found void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{  i not get any value in my current element

Comment: found character method was called , when there is some data between the xml tags.

Comment: what u given i try but it still not working can i sent u all element class and parser class and controller class

Comment: when did you sent the classes?

Comment: hi i edit the body with all class please cheek i cant sent u code from here bec ur server is blocked for sending purpose what i created i given all data in body please cheek above the body which i add now

Comment: Can you explian much more about your problem?

Comment: call this line in your didstart method   [self.currentElement appendString:string];

Comment: my problem is my xml values that have been fetched are not getting added to my array

Comment: do this where yo take elements as nsstring, take them as nsmutablearray and then where you parse the xml add the content into the array

Comment: i have done converting nsstring to nsmutablearray .but it does not produce the result

Comment: then why are you using different classes , do all things in one class , as its easy to do...

Comment: now can you send me some of the code in mail , so that i do it and help you solving your problem otherwise its difficult for me.You can upload it to any other uploading sites so that i can download it and made necessary changes

Comment: Aman i given u all class of parser sorry i cannot upload code i don't have asses for it i can search only nothing else my friend u can't copy code from stack and use it